# The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, bukkit

I'm getting the following error whilst trying to obfuscate my Java program (A spigot API plugin for a minecraft server)

```
Note: you're writing the processed class files to a directory [C:\Users\user\Desktop\OBFUSCATE\out].
      This will likely cause problems with obfuscated mixed-case class names.
      You should consider writing the output to a jar file, or otherwise
      specify '-dontusemixedcaseclassnames'.
Reading program jar [C:\Users\user\Desktop\OBFUSCATE\pvptimer.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\rt.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\user\Desktop\OBFUSCATE\paper-1613.jar]
Warning: class [META-INF/versions/9/com/destroystokyo/paperclip/Main.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.destroystokyo.paperclip.Main]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.destroystokyo.paperclip.Main]
Warning: class [META-INF/versions/9/com/destroystokyo/paperclip/Agent.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.destroystokyo.paperclip.Agent]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [com.destroystokyo.paperclip.Agent]
Reading library jar [C:\Users\user\Desktop\OBFUSCATE\patched_1.12.2.jar]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.ItemList]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.JSONArray]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.JSONAware]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.JSONObject]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.JSONStreamAware]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.JSONValue]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.parser.ContainerFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.parser.ContentHandler]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.parser.ParseException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.parser.Yylex]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.json.simple.parser.Yytoken]
Note: there were 14 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: there were 2 classes in incorrectly named files.
         You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
         The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
         If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
         you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

I'm just not sure how to fix this error. I have looked and found several online tutorials claiming to be able to fix this issue but to no avail.

If anyone has run into this issue and has been able to fix it, please share your wisdom!

Edit**:

After selecting the box `Ignore warnings about possibly erroneous input`, the obfuscation goes through, but upon loading the plugin, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the libraries your code that you are obfuscating depends on, or that other code in your project depends on your now-obfuscated code however its references are pointing to the method names of the unobfuscated jar. 
Let me know if that one flew past your head, I will try to explain it a bit better if I can.

A small example:

```
OldClass { //This class, has reference to LibClass.callMethod
   void oldMethod() { 
     LibClass.callMethod(); 
   }
}
```

```
LibClass {
   static void callMethod() { 
      //now if this gets obfuscated, 
      //and the above code is never renamed to this new obfuscated name
      // you will get errors like you are seeing (The method doesn't exist anymore)

   }
}
```

Comment: This is assuming i'm obfuscating the library files though right? If I dont obfuscate my libraries, why would this happen?

Comment: You don't need to obfuscate your libraries, you need to make sure that anything that references your code which is getting obfuscated, changes its references to the obfuscated naming

Comment: Nice answers! Keep going

Comment: Much appreciated :) *Adds friend*